# Installing Highstocks for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Do I have to do anything else other than add this to my gemfile?

```
gem 'highstock-rails'
```

Because if I go to the github account for it and add the require lines to my application.js the system still cannot find highstocks to use it in a script.

These are the lines I added:

> //= require highstock
>
> //= require highstock/highcharts-more

Comment: restart your server

Comment: I did and that wasn't working, but after correcting it and then adding the script line as an asset and calling it after the html loaded, seems to work now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not adding older version, and remove the `require_tree .` from your application.js file.  Like uzaif restart your server as well for good measure even though that wasn't particularly the issue I was having, it's a good idea anyway.